# Why do I get Syntax error while assigning dictionary by single line for loop?

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax

I tried to assign 'False' to dic[0] to dic[49] like this.

```
>>> dic = {}
>>> [ dic[i] = False for i in range(50)]
```

but, I got this error msg.

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [ dic[i] = False for i in range(50)]
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It worked by this way.

```
for i in range(50):
    dic[i] = False
```

Why can't I use single line for loop for assigning dictionary?

Comment: List comprehensions require an expression. Assignment is a statement, not an expression.

Comment: **That is not a single line loop**. That is a list comprehension, which is a functional programming construct to *express mapping and filtering operations* on iterables to produce a list. Again, **it is not a single-line for loop**, it's not meant to be used that way. You cannot use statements inside.

Comment: Thanks for all. I misunderstood concept of list comprehension!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `[dic[i] = False for i in range(50)]` is not *single for loop*, this is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to collect values.

What you need is [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (at the end of the `Dict` section)

```
dic = {i: False for i in range(50)}
```

Comment: Thnaks for your kind explanation~ ^_^